# Eclipse does not detect missing try/catch anymore?

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch, compiler-warnings

In this code

```
String a = "notANumber";
Integer b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

A try/catch is necessary since `parseInt` throws an `NumberFormatException` exception.
In my previous version of Eclipse, I used to got a warning telling that a try/catch was necessary but I can't figured out how to enable it on my current version of Eclipse which is

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`.

You don't *have* to put `try`/`catch` for runtime exceptions.

From [the javadoc of RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) :

> RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that can be
>   thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine.
>   RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>
> Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

And I seriously doubt any version of Eclipse required a `try/catch` for the code you show. You must be confused with another call (maybe a wrapper one declaring the exception, the fact the exception isn't checked doesn't mean you shouldn't, sometimes, explicitly catch it, in fact this one is probably most often explicitly catched).

Comment: +1. Also this resource describes the three kinds of exceptions : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: Yes you're right, it was an other exception for sure, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html):

[image]

It's a *Runtime Exception* - [It doesn't have to be checked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), so the compiler won't check it.

See the [JLS - 11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1) for more valuable information:

> The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and
>   the error classes.