# Why is eclipse not highlighting the code that is generating a checked exception?

Tags: java, eclipse

There's a line of code in my Java class file may result in an IOException that I need to catch. When I attempt to compile my code, I get

```
 error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[javac]         return cacheClientBuilder.build();
```

This makes sense. However I'am not seeing the error in Eclipse. I typically see this kind of error but I reinstalled Eclipse a couple of days ago.

I found a related question [related 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264613/eclipse-does-not-detect-missing-try-catch-anymore) but the exception in that question was a RuntimeException. A response in this question - [related 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706944/eclipse-find-lines-in-a-block-that-can-throw-exceptions) hinted that I should investigate the mark occurrences menu. I found the menu, enabled marking "Expressions throwing a declared exception" and then set the color of marked occurrences to the red and applied the configuration. However there is still no detection by Eclipse of the possible IOException. Anybody know what setting/step I'am missing? I've attached screenshots of the process I went through as well.

Screenshots of process:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is off topic. This fits - "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is "  of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I assume the CacheClient is coming from from a library. Are you using maven or gradle? Maybe Eclipse uses a different version of lib than your complier. Refreshing the maven or gradle context may help